# CSS weirdness from overflow:hidden

Tags: css, overflow

At least I think it's from overflow hidden.

I've got a bunch of divs as inline-blocks. They each have an image that is bigger than the set 50x50, with overflow hidden set. Sometimes on load, the images don't settle quite right:

[image: https://img.skitch.com/20111112-8nr1nur9ts5hd8cy7uumh3ft21.jpg]

But if I right click to inspect element, it immediately settles (Chrome). Safari has a similar behavior.

Expected result:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="thumb_overlay">        
            <div class="active">
                <img src="1.jpg" data-src="a.jpg">
            </div>

            <div>
                <img src="2.jpg" data-src="b.jpg">
            </div>

            <div>
                <img src="3.jpg" data-src="c.jpg">
            </div>


            ... etc
</div>
```

css:

```
#thumb_overlay {
position: absolute;
bottom: 5px;
right: 5px;
text-align: right;
background-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .5);
padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;
}

#thumb_overlay > div {
display: inline-block;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
overflow: hidden;
}

#thumb_overlay img {
opacity: .9;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Maybe just add a width to the thub_overlay?

Comment: I don't know how many images are going to be in it. Could do so in js I suppose.

Comment: Do you have this online anywhere?

Comment: Your code looks perfectly good to me. This sounds like a browser bug, and one I can't reproduce with just the HTML/CSS you've provided. Can you provide the full html/css of the page? There must be something else going on, maybe some javascript or other css rule.

Comment: It's a locked site right now, so I can't show it. I'm just going to float them, it works well enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it as display: block and float them next to each other instead of inlining them, I've had similar problems with absolute positioning and letting the browser position them automatically seemed to stop the mouseover issue.

Comment: Good call. I'll try it out. I'll have to move some margin to the individual divs, and do some :first and :last fanciness, which I was hoping to avoid. But, so far, only option.

Comment: Float is going to cause more problems than it solves, for example the browser won't be able to determine the width/height of `#thumb_overlay`. Inline-block is the correct display type.